# CGRectApplyAffineTransformを適用されたCGRectを元に戻したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

CGAffineTransform の影響で変更された CGRect の値を元に戻すにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

以下が検証として取り組んでいる変換例で、point(10,10), size(100, 100) の四角形を 45 度傾けています。

```
// 初期状態
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);                          // {{10, 10}, {100, 100}}
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;             // [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

// 45度回転させる
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f); // [0.70710677, 0.70710677, -0.70710677, 0.70710677, 0, 0]
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, rotate);              // [0.70710677, 0.70710677, -0.70710677, 0.70710677, 0, 0]
rect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, transform);                  // {{-70.710678, 14.142136}, {141.42136, 141.42136}}

// rectを初期状態に復元したい
// ...？
```

以下のコードはダメでした。

```
rect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, CGAffineTransformInvert(transform)); // {{-40, -40}, {200, 200}}
```

ちなみに、

```
CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, CGAffineTransformInvert(transform)) // [0.99999994, 0, 0, 0.99999994, 0, 0]
```

であり、誤差はあるものの、行列自体は CGAffineTransformInvert() で戻せるようです。が、CGRect が期待どおりに戻りません。

実際に使用する際は、初期状態が CGAffineTransformIdentity とは限らず、どのような行列が適用されているかはわかりません。また、CGAffineTransformIdentity なときの CGRect も取得できるとは限りません。言い換えれば、ある行列が既に適用済みの CGRect から CGAffineTransformIdentity な状態の CGRect を算出するのが目的です。

今回の例では、45度傾けることで `{{-70.710678, 14.142136}, {141.42136, 141.42136}}` になってしまったものを `{{10, 10}, {100, 100}}` に変換できれば成功です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGRectの仕様として原点の座標とサイズを保持するようになっているため、45度傾けた時点でCGRectのサイズが拡大されてしまいます。
（長方形を紙に描いて、傾けてみればわかりやすいかと思います）

これを避ける場合、元のCGRectから四隅に該当するCGPointを生成して、それぞれ別々に変換させるのが楽かと思います。こうしておけば、CGAffineTransformInvert()でそれぞれのCGPointを元の位置に戻すことが出来ます。

以下Swiftですが、試しにやってみました。

```
// CGRectの四隅をCGPointに変換
func rectToPoints(rect: CGRect) -> [CGPoint] {
    var ar = [CGPoint]()
    ar.append(CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    ar.append(CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
    ar.append(CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    ar.append(CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    return ar
}

// CGPointをCGRectに変換
func pointsToRect(points: [CGPoint]) -> CGRect {
    var min_x = points[0].x
    var max_x = points[0].x
    var min_y = points[0].y
    var max_y = points[0].y

    for pos in points {
        min_x = min(min_x, pos.x)
        max_x = max(max_x, pos.x)
        min_y = min(min_y, pos.y)
        max_y = max(max_y, pos.y)
    }
    return CGRect(x: min_x, y: min_y, width: max_x-min_x, height: max_y-min_y)
}

// 初期状態
let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)
let transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

// 45度回転させる
let rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(45.0 * M_PI / 180.0))
let transform2 = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, rotate)
let rect2 = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, transform2)

// ここまでは、Objective-CのコードをSwiftに直しただけ

// 四隅を別々にしてから45度回転
let point = rectToPoints(rect)
let point2 = point.map() { pos in CGPointApplyAffineTransform(pos, transform2) }
let rect3 = pointsToRect(point2)    // {x -70.711 y 14.142 w 141.421 h 141.421}

// 四隅を別々に逆変換
let invert = CGAffineTransformInvert(transform2)
let point3 = point2.map() { pos in CGPointApplyAffineTransform(pos, invert) }
let rect4 = pointsToRect(point3)    // {x 10 y 10 w 100 h 100}
```

**補足**: 回答内関数のObjective-C版を付記します

```
// e.g.)
// CGPoint points[4];
// [self rectToPoints: rect points: points];
- (void)rectToPoints:(CGRect)rect points:(CGPoint[4])points {

  points[0] = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
  points[1] = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
  points[2] = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
  points[3] = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
}

// e.g.)
// CGRect rect = [self pointsToRect: points];
- (CGRect)pointsToRect:(CGPoint[4])points {

  CGFloat minX = points[0].x;
  CGFloat maxX = points[0].x;
  CGFloat minY = points[0].y;
  CGFloat maxY = points[0].y;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    minX = fminf(minX, points[i].x);
    maxX = fmaxf(maxX, points[i].x);
    minY = fminf(minY, points[i].y);
    maxY = fmaxf(maxY, points[i].y);
  }

  return CGRectMake(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。「元のCGRect」とありますが、質問文にあるように CGAffineTransformIdentity なときの CGRect、つまり「元のCGRect」が得られるとは限らないのですが、「元のCGRect」なしでこの方法は成り立ちますか？

Comment: 残念ながら成り立ちません。変換後のCGRectと変換に使われたCGAffineTransformだけで、元のCGRectを正確に求めるのは無理かと思います。

Comment: なるほど。ということは、元のCGRectを取得すること方法や、それを保持しておく構造を考えるのに力を注いだほうが良さそうですね。問題への取り組み方を変えてみます！

Answer (score 1):

質問者様の正確な回答かわかりませんが、`{{10, 10}, {100, 100}}`へ戻す方法です。
swiftで失礼します。

```
var button : UIButton = UIButton()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    //SwiftだとM_PIがdouble型なので、CGFloatへ
    let endAngle:CGFloat =  CGFloat(M_PI)
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(endAngle / 4);
    println(button.frame)
}
func didTapButton(sender : UIButton)
{
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    println(button.frame)
}
```

log

```
//回転した状態
(-10.7106781186547,-10.7106781186548,141.42135623731,141.42135623731)
//タップ後の状態
(10.0,10.0,100.0,100.0)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし、質問文にある通り「初期状態が CGAffineTransformIdentity とは限らず」という条件も視野に入れての課題となっています

Comment: もうひとつ補足しますと、この方法の場合は一度ビューへ CGAffineTransformIdentity を適用しないといけませんが、常にビューの表示を変更できるとは限らないため、この方法が使用できません。ダミーのビューを生成して使うにしても、元ビューの transform は取得できますが CGAffineTransformIdentity 時の frame がわかりません（レイヤのモデル層、プレゼンテーション層ともに transform の影響で frame が既に変化している可能性があります）。そのため、どのような状況でも通用する逆変換法として `{{-70.710678, 14.142136}, {141.42136, 141.42136}}` を `{{10, 10}, {100, 100}}` に **変換** する方法を知りたいと考えています

Comment: @dokubeko 勘違いしていました。CGRectApplyAffineTransformを使い、CGRect自体に変化を加える方法では、`button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`では、戻せませんでした。
例の45度傾ける段階で、`button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(endAngle / 4)`のような方法で変化を加えている場合のみ、`button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`の方法で、変化前のCGRectへ戻すことが可能です。

Comment: はい。ビューに変更が加えることができるとは限らないため、CGRectApplyAffineTransform で、数値変換のみによる適用結果の予測や、逆変換をしたい状況です。なかなか糸口が掴めませぬ・・・